# How to store arrays of pixels in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to create a small image editing program in Python with Pygame. I want to store the array of pixels the app is working on, so I can have undo/redo features and zoom. How would I go about this?

I have tried storing the pixels as lists of rgb values within lists within lists, like so:

```
x1 = [[255, 255, 255]]
x2 = [[255, 0, 0]]
y1 = [x1, x2]
```

But I have a hard time believing that is the best way by any means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talking about `undo/redo` , please check the [Command Design Pattern](https://github.com/gennad/Design-Patterns-in-Python/blob/master/command.py) (python example).

Since you didn't provide much code , the basic approach could rely on maintaining a unique list with your coordinates. The one thing that should change that list is a `Command` which will contain `undo` and `redo`methods to restore the list state.

**Update**

I'm not sure I fully understood what exactly you are trying to achieve , but a `dictionary` may serve you:

```
coords = {}
coords['y1'] = [[255,255,255],[255,0,0]] #add dynamic keys to your dictionary and fill them with the right values
```

You also get a plus here if needed to **store** or **transfer** your data later, you can simply get your data in `JSON` format like this:

```
import json
... 
json.dumps(coords) #returns the json string containing your data
```

Comment: Interesting, but I was more interested in any other format to store the data in - chiefly to implement zoom and such. I know lists would work, so in that case, would I use one very long list, or lists of lists? And inheritance seems a very nice way to do commands and such, thank you!